# How to return a single DataRow object from Asp Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

So I am writing some Asp.Net WebApi code to hook with old C# back-end code where there is no model class used. (Pure dataTable returned from DataAccess, Crazy right? I know)

Following is the code I put on the Server side.

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int campaignID, int productID)
    {
        var so = new SearchOptions(campaignID)
        {
            ProductID = productID
        };

        var result = SearchManager.Search(so);
        if (result == null || result.Rows.Count == 0)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(result.Rows[0]);

    }
```

I am expecting to have the response like this:

```
{
Field1: "field1",
Field2: "field2",
...
}
```

But Actually I am having this:

```
{
  "rowError": "",
  "rowState": 2,
  "table": [
    {
      Field1 : "field1",
      Field2 : "field2",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "itemArray": ["field1","field2"],
  "hasErrors": false
}
```

I don't want all these `rowError`, `rowState`...etc

If I am doing this on the server side:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int campaignID, int productID)
        {
            var so = new SearchOptions(campaignID)
            {
                ProductID = productID
            };

            var result = SearchManager.Search(so);
            if (result == null || result.Rows.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(result);

        }
```

I am receiving this:

```
[{Field1: "field1", Field2: "field2"..}]
```

which is unfortunately rejected by `ngResource` get method since it is an array rather than a single Json Object.

What should I do? If I just want to return a single dataRow as a Json string.

Ideally I want to avoid go down to the path of creating an Response Object as suggested by Manoz. (Thank you for your answer Manoz though)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `DataRow` to `Dictionary` using LINQ:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int campaignID, int productID)
{
    var so = new SearchOptions(campaignID)
    {
        ProductID = productID
    };

    var result = SearchManager.Search(so);
    if (result == null || result.Rows.Count == 0)
        return NotFound();

    var row = result.Rows[0];
    return Ok(row.Table.Columns
        .Cast<DataColumn>()
        .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => row[c]));
}
```

That action returns JSON as you want: `{ Field1: "field1", Field2: "field2", ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try deserializing it?

```
Using NewtonSoft.Json
```

Create a separate class matching your response. I believe response's format will remain same always.

```
public class Response{
    public List<response> table{ get;set; }
}

public class response {
    public string Field1 { get;set; }
    public string Field2 { get;set; }
}
```

Now deserializing response using Newtonsoft.Json

```
var entities = SearchManager.Search(so);

var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(entities)
var endResult= result.table[0] //will get you result
```

Help source - https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: Thanks. But sorry I will update my OP. Because I am trying to avoid creating a Model for the Response.

Comment: then why can't you simply query - `result.Rows[0].table[0]` ?

Comment: It returns me an array again. Same as `Ok(result)`

Comment: can't be same. You are lying ;D

Comment: anyways just tried this here - http://jsonpath.com/

with query equalant to - `result.Rows[0].table[0]` ==> `$.table[0]`

see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Since this posted just a few months ago, assume you're using API 2.x. This version handles return format automatically and intelligently, particularly no need to implement explicit CAST. You just need to specify the type you want. For example in AngularJS, this will tell API what you're expecting:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'json'
  url: ...
}).then(function mySuccess(response){
  $scope.theRow = response.data;
})
```

At server API, just keep your code. During execution, it will auto-return result in JSON format.

Comment: Again, no need to CAST at all.